# FIlter array of data with dropdown without pipe Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, drop-down-menu

I need to filter data by selected dropdown item.
It currently searches me only once when I select filters and after that it is always empty.
Example:

```
        <select class="select" (change)="onChangeMeal($event)">
            <option value="Izaberit">Choice meal</option>
            <option *ngFor="let meal of mealType" [value]="meal.num">
                {{ meal.name }}
            </option>
        </select>



onChangeMeal(evt) {

let mealTypeNumber = evt.target.value;
console.log(mealTypeNumber);

  switch (mealTypeNumber) {
  case '0':
    this.meals = this.meals.filter(meal => meal.trainerId == '0')
    console.log('0 meal' , this.meals)
    break;

  case '1':
    this.meals = this.meals.filter(meal => meal.trainerId == '1')
    console.log('1 meal' , this.meals)
    break;

  case '2':
    this.meals = this.meals.filter(meal => meal.trainerId == '2')
    break;

  case '3':
    this.meals = this.meals.filter(meal => meal.trainerId == '3')
    break;

  default:
    break;
}

// if(evt.target.value == '1') {
//   console.log('jes')
//   this.meals = this.meals.filter(meal => meal.trainerId == '1')  
// }
// if(evt.target.value == '2') {
//   console.log('jes 2')
//   this.meals = this.meals.filter(meal => meal.trainerId == '2')  
// }
```

}

He does it only once again. The next time I try to select a dropdown value it returns an empty array.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

Don't `filter` the array directly, because you will lose all items in the array that do not meet the `filter` criteria.

Instead, hold the items in another variable and use that one to filter

```
allItems = [...this.meals];
// [...]
this.meals = allItems.filter(() => {});
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/G4QwTgBAtgpiA2BnCBeCBtAjAJgMwBoAWAVgDZ8B2ADgE4BdAbgFgAoV0SBeASQBcYoyNOgB0Y2AkSNWEpKghc+AxCIBmAS3j8wACnX8oqAHwR9A1CjQlSASmYsAxgHsAdoifwYI+E4DmO2UQ7GTg5NEUDFQ0tGF0zQxQTeIs0HFxgx1d3T28-ANCg+1ZnNw8vH38I5TsgA)

Comment: Hmm, i am to do in your way but same situation. Same. let allMealsClone = [...this.meals] and this.meals = allMealsClone.filter(meal => meal.trainerId == '0')

Comment: @pekamap9 It is working, check the added example. If your issue keeps persisting, consider making a reproducible example, showing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're updating your `meals` data so that the other cases might not work as intended. You need to assign your `meals` data with another variable like

```
....subscribe(res) => {
  // here you need to assign in two different variables
  this.allMeals = res;
  this.meals = res;
}
```

Then in your cases instead of filtering from `meals`, you need to filter from `this.allMeals` and assign result to `meals` variable.

```
case '2':
    this.meals = this.allMeals.filter(meal => meal.trainerId == '2')
    break;
```

In this case your `meals` will have a filtered result from `allMeals` every time.